# mongodb taking too much time for old entries

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i am new in mongodb and i am facing an issue,
 i have around millions of documents in my collection
and i am trying to find single entry using findOne({}) command
 and when i am trying to find recent entries then response comes in miliseconds 
 but when i am trying to fetch older entries around 600 millionth document then it takes around 2 minutes on mongo shell
 and my node server gives

```
{ MongoErro : connection 1 to 127.0.0.1:27017 timed out }
```

and my nodejs server sends an empty response.
 can any one tell me what should i do to resolve this issue
Thanks in advance

explain gives me

```
    db.contacts.find({"phoneNumber":"9165900137"}).explain("executionStats")
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "meanApp.contacts",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "phoneNumber" : {
                                "$eq" : "9165900137"
                        }
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "phoneNumber" : {
                                        "$eq" : "9165900137"
                                }
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 1,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 321188,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 495587806,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                                "phoneNumber" : {
                                        "$eq" : "9165900137"
                                }
                        },
                        "nReturned" : 1,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 295230,
                        "works" : 495587808,
                        "advanced" : 1,
                        "needTime" : 495587806,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 3871779,
                        "restoreState" : 3871779,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "direction" : "forward",
                        "docsExamined" : 495587806
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "li1025-15.members.linode.com",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.16",
                "gitVersion" : "056bf45128114e44c5358c7a8776fb582363e094"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: You need to provide details, like your query, your indexes, results of the `explain` you've surely already run, how the dupes here on SO weren't sufficiently helpful, etc.

Comment: Voting this question up makes no sense-it's equivalent to saying "why doesn't my program work" and little else. There's no information here anybody could use to help beyond the typical and duplicate "how do I make mongo fast" questions here and on the web. There may not be reasons to downvote, but are most certainly reasons not to upvote.

Comment: And your indices? ` explain` result? Etc.

Comment: Yep, got that. What else?

Comment: Also, this information should go into the question, not into comments.

Comment: 'db.contact.findOne({"contactNum":"9165900137"}).explain("executionStats")' gives me nothing it's executing but no output

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain

Comment: And your indices are...? Please edit the question with the relevant information. Please provide the information requested. Please search SO and the web as this type of question, and the steps to remediate many types of slow queries, are all over.

Comment: So no index? What would you expect? It'll have to do a full collection scan. This is why indices exist. I see back in September it was much the same process to get information. Please re-read my comments, and Neil's comments from September, and consider a different approach to asking questions. Good luck!

Comment: Unrelated, but you have not "around millions of documents", you have two orders of magnitude note than that-you have half a billion documents, and it's looking at each one.

Comment: is there any way to point my documents directly because i am looking at each document to match my number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the explain plan results, the current query is doing Collection Scan. This means it has to scan every document in collection to produce the match and you have got about half a billion documents.

Try adding this index and it might take a bit to create it.

> db.contacts.createIndex( { phoneNumber: 1 }, { background: true } )

Run the query once the index creation is successful, you must see a dramatic improvement in performance. To be certain whether index got picked up, try explain again and it should no longer say COLLSCAN.

Comment: Any questions or comments on the answer provided? Otherwise please accept the answer (the small tick mark)